# changing format of a string to calculate duration in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate the duration time from column start time and end time. I have them in this format as string '00:00:00'
I'm thinking of to replacing every ':' with '.' so I can easily subtract them as double type to calculate the duration.

To achieve this I tried this code:

```
startT=list()
endT=list()
for ind,row in df.iterrows():
 startT=(dataframe['Chat Session Initiation Time'].astype(str).str[10:19]).replace(':','.')
 endT=(dataframe['Chat Session End Time'].astype(str).str[10:19]).replace(':','.')
```

the substring I'm doing is to get the time alone from the text.
this code does not replace the characters as I wished. I need help with that.

and If you have a better way to calculate the duration let me know kindly

Comment: You just need convert these columns to datetime values.  You can do arithmetic with datetime values just like integers.  Remember that 00.19.39 is not a valid float.

Comment: you could get differences between datetime objects easily

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Comment: @Tim Roberts
i tried usin astype(datetime) did not work did i do it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [ 0, "00:00:00", "00:01:19" ],
    [ 1, "00:15:50", "00:45:19" ],
    [ 2, "01:30:05", "02:01:19" ],
    [ 3, "04:29:10", "05:00:00" ]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['index','start','stop'])
print(df)
df['start'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['start'])
df['stop'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['stop'])
df['diff'] = df['stop'] - df['start']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   index     start      stop
0      0  00:00:00  00:01:19
1      1  00:15:50  00:45:19
2      2  01:30:05  02:01:19
3      3  04:29:10  05:00:00
   index           start            stop            diff
0      0 0 days 00:00:00 0 days 00:01:19 0 days 00:01:19
1      1 0 days 00:15:50 0 days 00:45:19 0 days 00:29:29
2      2 0 days 01:30:05 0 days 02:01:19 0 days 00:31:14
3      3 0 days 04:29:10 0 days 05:00:00 0 days 00:30:50
```

You can also use `to_datetime`, but that assumes today's date.  The math still works out, it just prints other than what you expect.